# How to write junit test for a java class that create object using new inside functions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have one java class for which i have to write junit test. The class is create on param that is used to call another method. The test is failing due to the diff ref for same object.

```
public MyClass {
     public MyResult myMethod(String a, String b, String c) {
         MyRequest m = new MyRequest();
         m.setA(a);
         m.setB(b);
         m.setC(c);
         MyResult ms = myService.getResult(m);
         log(ms);
         return ms;
    }
}
```

This is the test class.

```
@PrepareForTest({ MyService.class, MyClass.class })
public class MyClassTest {
   @InjectMocks
   MyClass myClass;

   @Mock
   MyService myService;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void myMethod() {
      String a = "a", b="b", c="c";
      MyRequest m = new MyRequest();
      m.setA(a);
      m.setB(b);
      m.setC(c);

      MyResult response = mock(MyResult.class);
      when(myService.getResult(m)).thenReturn(response);

      MyResult result = myClass.myMethod(a, b, c);
      assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the test case?

Comment: If the fail is due to ref diff, maybe you are missing an equals method on your class MyResult ?

Comment: yes some problem with the ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below Mockito set up. It will accept MyRequest class and will execute your code.

```
Mockito.when(myService.getResult(Mockito.any(MyRequest.class))).thenReturn(new MyResult());
```